# Find xpath of an element using text

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="css-ki-menu">
<div class="css-11ur">
<div class="css-d0i-option" id="react-select-3-option-0" tabindex="-1">L3</div>
<div class="css-f5s-option" id="react-select-3-option-1" tabindex="-1">L4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have the text 'L3' is there any way to find the relative xpath using the text?

Please help me out am new to it

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specifc? And can you provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Thnx

Answer (score 0):

To locate element with `L3` text as in the example provided you can simply use `//div[contains(text(),'L3')]` or  `//div[text()='L3']`
If you need this `xpath` to be relative to some other element - please provide more details.